# I am unable to play an MP3 file on Raspberry Pi Pico using the DY-SV8F module

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I recently acquired the DY-SV8F module and a Micro SD adapter module for the raspberry pi pico, my purpose of this was that from the Micro SD was saved an MP3 file to be played through the DY-SV8F.

I tried to do it this way but without much success, since I only managed to play an MP3 file that comes by default in the flash memory of the DY-SV8F.

```
import machine
import sdcard
import uos
import time


# Configuration of DY-SV8F output pins
txd_pin = machine.Pin(16, machine.Pin.OUT)
tck_pin = machine.Pin(17, machine.Pin.OUT)
busy_pin = machine.Pin(18, machine.Pin.IN)


# Configuration of chip select (CS) for the micro SD card
cs_pin = machine.Pin(1, machine.Pin.OUT)


# Initialize SPI for the micro SD card
spi = machine.SPI(0,
                  baudrate=1000000,
                  polarity=0,
                  phase=0,
                  bits=8,
                  firstbit=machine.SPI.MSB,
                  sck=machine.Pin(2),
                  mosi=machine.Pin(3),
                  miso=machine.Pin(4))


# Initialize the micro SD card
sd = sdcard.SDCard(spi, cs_pin)


# Mount the file system
uos.mount(sd, '/sd')


# Function to send commands to the DY-SV8F module
def send_command(cmd):
    txd_pin.off()
    tck_pin.off()
    time.sleep_us(100)


    for i in range(8):
        txd_pin.value((cmd >> (7 - i)) & 1)
        tck_pin.on()
        time.sleep_us(100)
        tck_pin.off()
        time.sleep_us(100)


    txd_pin.on()
    tck_pin.on()
    time.sleep_us(100)
    tck_pin.off()
    time.sleep_us(100)


# Function to play an MP3 file
def play_mp3(file_path):
    # Stop current playback (if any)
    send_command(0xAA)
    send_command(0x04)
    time.sleep(0.1)


    # Open the MP3 file from the micro SD card
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        # Read file data and send it to DY-SV8F.
        byte = file.read(1)
        while byte != b"":
            send_command(ord(byte))
            byte = file.read(1)
    # Start playback
    send_command(0xAA)
    send_command(0x02)
    time.sleep(0.1)


# Path of the MP3 file on the micro SD card
mp3_file_path = "/sd/my_file.mp3"


# Play the MP3 file
play_mp3(mp3_file_path)
```

The specific module is this: https://es.aliexpress.com/i/33057596068.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2esp

That a simple mp3 file stored on the micro SD would be played.

Comment: What DOES happen when you choose a different file?  Are you able to read the file?  Does the unit have a length limit?  Does your file have metadata?  It may be the unit can't handle metadata.